# SQL Bulk insert ignores first data row

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to import a pipeline delimited file into a temporary table using bulk insert (UTF-8 with unix style row terminator), but it keeps ignoring the first data row (the one after the header) and i don't know why.
Adding `|` to the header row will not help either...

File contents:

```
SummaryFile_20191017140001.dat|XXXXXXXXXX|FIL-COUNTRY|128
File1_20191011164611.dat|2|4432|2|Imported||
File2_20191011164611.dat|3|4433|1|Imported||
File3_20191011164611.dat|4|4433|2|Imported||
File4_20191011164611.dat|5|4434|1|Imported|INV_ERROR|
File5_20191011164611.dat|6|4434|2|Imported||
File6_20191011164611.dat|7|4434|3|Imported||
```

The bulk insert throws no error, but it keeps ignoring the first data line (File1_...)

SQL below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mycsv') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #mycsv

create table #mycsv
    (
        tlr_file_name   varchar(150) null,
        tlr_record_id   int null,
        tlr_pre_invoice_number  varchar(50) null,
        tlr_pre_invoice_line_number varchar(50) null,
        tlr_status  varchar (30) null,
        tlr_error_code  varchar(30) null,
        tlr_error_message   varchar (500) null)

bulk insert #mycsv 
from 'D:\TestData\Test.dat' 
with (
    rowterminator = '0x0A',
    fieldTerminator = '|',
    firstrow = 2, 
    ERRORFILE = 'D:\TestData\Import.log')

select * from #mycsv
```

It's really bugging me, since i don't really know what am i missing.
If i specify `FirstRow = 1` th script will throw: 
`Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 2 (tlr_record_id).`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm baffled.  Your first row contains column headers.  You don't really want them in your table, do you?  You *want* to skip the first row.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i copied the wrong version, which throws error...  edited

Comment: I think you need to add "|||" three delimiters to the header, to match the data rows, else header is ignored, and "first" data row is treated as row 1, and skipped. See full answer below. Problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"UTF-8 with unix style row terminator"* I assume you're using a version of SQL Server that doesn't support UTF-8. From [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **** Important **** Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).

If you *are* using 2016+, then specify the code page for UTF-8:

```
BULK INSERT #mycsv
FROM 'D:\TestData\Test.dat'
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
      FIRSTROW = 1,
      CODEPAGE = '65001',
      ERRORFILE = 'D:\TestData\Import.log');
```

If you aren't using SQL Server 2016+, then you *cannot* use `BULK INSERT` to import a **UTF-8** file; you will have to use a different code page or use a different tool.

---

Note, also, that the above document states the below:

> The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers. Skipping headers is not supported by the BULK INSERT statement. When skipping rows, the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the field terminators, and does not validate the data in the fields of skipped rows.

if you are skipping rows, you still need to ensure the row is valid, but it's not for skipping headers. This means you should be using `FIRSTROW = 1` and fixing your header row as @sarlacii points out.

Of course, that does not fix the code page problem if you are using an older version of SQL Server; and my point stands that you'll have to use a different technology on 2014 and prior.

Comment: i tried converting the file in ANSI but the result is the same. Also tried adding `Codepage = 'ACP'`but still ignored. I have SQL server 2016, 2014, 2008R2 and on each of them the first lins is ignored. I'll try importing every line then, and just delete the first from temp table.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to account for this, @LeviTheOne , prior to your comment. You need to fix your header and not skip it; there is no header skipping with `BULK INSERT`

Comment: Ok, by correcting the header and updating the data type from `int` to `varchar` for `tlr_record_id` is working, (imports including the header) but what if i can't modify the file? In the normal flow i can't modify the file, only read data from it.

Comment: Then the file isn't a valid Delimited File, @LeviTheOne and cannot be imported by processes that expect a valid Delimited File (such as `BULK INSERT`). It's not the fault of the import process if the file is malformed; that's the exporters problem and they need to fix their set up.

Comment: Interesting, but I'd expect BULK INSERT to work like:
once i specified a row terminator the first thing should be to split the data in rows, then, split a row into columns:
if the number of col. sep. + 1 doesn't equals the number of columns from table just fill the table row with default(Type) or null, or if there are more separators, then shift the data into a new row (where do the same). TO avoid this kind of problems, it would be nice to have an eager validation on file structure, and the only reason when error should be raised is when cast exception occurs. Why/where am i wrong?

Comment: Also i accepted this answer since it helped the most,  and sorry for the delay on response time

Answer (score 0):

To import rows effectively into a SQL database, it is important to make the header formatting match the data rows. Add the missing delimiters, like so, to the header and try the import again:

```
SummaryFile_20191017140001.dat|XXXXXXXXXX|FIL-COUNTRY|128|||
```

The number of fields in the header, versus the data fields, must match, else the row is ignored, and the first satisfactory "data" row will be treated as the header.

Comment: there is no `Load data local infile` in MS-SQL